# What's going wrong in conversion of bytes back to numpyndarray?

Tags: numpy, tcp, raspberry-pi3, tcpclient

I successfully established a tcp connection between my pc and raspberry pi. By sending strings, now I am looking forward to send numpy arrays, basically images over the connection this is my code for server:

```
import socket
import pickle
import cv2
import numpy as np
s = socket.socket()
host = '192.168.137.171' #ip of raspberry pi
port = 12346
s.bind((host, port))
cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
s.listen(5)
while True:
  ret,frame=cam.read()
  #frame=pickle.dumps(frame)
  frame=np.ndarray.tobytes(frame)
  c, addr = s.accept()
  print ('Got connection from',addr)
  c.send(frame)
  #c.send(bytes(frame,"utf-8"))
  c.close()
```

Using this I am transferring numpy array, by converting it to bytes using the function np.ndarray.tobytes(). After excecution of the following code, here is the client end code that is the one which is to be executed by my pc:

```
import socket               
import numpy as np
s = socket.socket()        
host = '192.168.137.171'# ip of raspberry pi 
port = 12346              
s.connect((host, port))
while True:
    print(type(s.recv(1024)))
    x=np.frombuffer(s.recv(1024), dtype=np.uint8)
s.close()
```

Now after execution of all this, I expected to decode bytes back to numpy ndarray and recieve an image but when I use

```
 cv2.imshow('x',x)
```

I just get a blank grey display. Where is it going wrong?

Comment: in which block is  `cv2.imshow("x", x)`? if it is not in while loop you are showing just one frame.

Comment: Hey Mitiku! Thanks... Even with one frame, it should atleast display one proper frame but what all its showing is just a gray blank window. :(